# Http POST Request in .Net Core

Tags: .net, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created application using Angular 5 with .net core 2.0.

```
public class RoadSignController : Controller
{
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("api/RoadSign/RegisterUser")]
     public void RegisterUser(User user)
     {
        repoWrapper.userRepo.Create(user);
     }
}
```

Also in Angular service I have put this code. Process is executing until angular service but not moving to controller.

```
Register(user: User) {
    return this._http.post(this.myAppUrl + 'api/RoadSign/RegisterUser', user).map((response: Response) => response.json()).catch(this.errorHandler)
}
```

Comment: This is hard to diagnose with so little information in the question but my first guess would be that it’s a CORS issue.

Comment: What error did you get in web browser? Try `F12` to check the error. Try to change action to `public void RegisterUser([FromBody]User user)`. A reproducable demo would be helpful.